# Android Studio doesnt open project correctly

Tags: android

When I import or open a project it doesn't open correctly and in the event log I get the message "Frameworks detected: Android framework is detected in the project Configure". Searching in google it says to install the support library but it's already installed

### SOLUTION

Refer to the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231460/frameworks-detected-in-android-studio)

Comment: That didn't fix. I also uninstalled and installed the sdk again

Comment: Anyone else get this problem? I'm having this exact problem too after messing around with my packages in Android SDK.

Comment: I don' remember exactly what i did to fix this but maybe it was the project repository messed up

Comment: @cybersam who cares if it is a duplicate question, there is no correct answer on that thread either. The only viable answer is to create a new project. What is a better solution for this issue?

Comment: I also encounter this problem, and no solution so far

Comment: Same Problem here. Any solution please.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problems while opening a project. Please make sure when the Android Studio do the conversion or build the Gradle files , you look into the Gradle's build file and check which particular version's SDK and build tools are required to build this particular project. Then also confirm from the SDK Manager (Tools->Android->SDK Manager) that tools of given version are installed.