# Frameworks detected in android studio

Tags: android

Frameworks detected: Android framework is detected in the project Configure

I get the above message when I try to build a particular project in android studio 1.4

The project is blank, and not able to run this project. I searched for the solution and didn't find any proper solution.

I came across this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18394291/5093415 , but according to this, in my case "Android Support Repository" is already been installed in sdk manager. This solution doesn't help me.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 32):

Following these instructions, they worked for me

1. Press **CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S**. Or Go to **File**> **Project Structure**
2. Go to **Project Setting** > **Facets**.
3. Click **+** button and add **Android-gradle**.
4. Select your project name.
5. Click Apply and Ok.
6. Close your project and reopen.
7. Wait until gradle finishes build your project.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you @user3123347

Comment: @ELITE try press CMD + ;

Comment: I did not find the option of Android-gradle on + click

Comment: Step 2 is actually Project structure -> Facets

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you have to import the project properly and not just opening?

Goto to **File** > **New Projec**t > **Import Project** *and browse for the project*...

Answer (score 5):

You might have just opened the wrong folder, like the folder ABOVE the project folder. (What I did.) Android Studio will create a .idea folder and open an empty project. If this is the case, delete the created .idea folder and select File>Open and navigate to the correct project folder.

Answer (score 4):

NO need to play with your project files..

1. Close all currently opened projects in Android Studio
2. Restart studio, select "Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)" (studio ver:2.1.2)

done!

Comment: This should be selected as a correct answer. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If Android Studio notices a difference in the path to the android SDK folder on disk and the path mentioned in your local.properties file, it will prompt and upon confirmation update the path in local.properties. I think you local.properties file is not retaining the change in SDK path once you close the project. Check you check if something is reverting the changes.

Also, try saving the `local.properties` file manually after updating the `sdk.dir` property with correct path..

It looks like this in the `local.properties` file.

```
# change the SDK path below to match the folder on your system
sdk.dir=D\:\\Android\\android-sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this error once in a while as well,
What helped for me is file -> close project and then re-open.

Comment: Are you using any version control? Discarding IDEA files and re-opening might work.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody finds like me that none of the suggested solutions fix this problem then a simple Invalidate Caches / Restart could fix the issue.

I struggled with this problem for months on just the one project, every time I wanted to work on it I had to remove and re-import the project.

Answer (score 0):

Adding under facets didn't work for me. 
What did:
Right click on your project in the Project pane on the left > Open Module Settings > Modules > Click the + to add a module > Android-Gradle

I also needed to modify some of the paths listed for the manifest/resources/assets etc in my Android module